# Service Broker queue message

Tags: sql-server, queue, service-broker

I'm facing some problems with my MSSQL instance which has a database (AuditMaster) that logs Audits from a client database (AuditClient for example).

The log (MSSQL log) is getting spammed with this message:

**An exception occurred while enqueueing a message in the target queue. Error: 33019, State: 1. Cannot create implicit user for the special login 'sa'**.

My questions are: target queue -> which queue? 
Cannot create implicit user for the special login 'sa' -> does this mean that you can't pass sa to another object?

Does someone have a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Following this guide (http://alstechtips.blogspot.be/2014/02/sql-server-2008-exception-occurred.html), I've changed the owners of the AuditMaster and clients to 'SA' (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359(v=sql.105).aspx). So far so good, the logs remain stable.

So maybe one of my clients tried to send a message to the target queue using 'SA', which can't be used implicit? I'm in the dark here...

Comment: I'm digging deeper into this problematic and found an interesting question on stackexchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18610/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-database-owner:

the most important thing: the database owner has important side effects, specifically the EXECUTE AS context. This later problem is what burns most users. Since Service Broker makes extensive use of EXECUTE AS (the message delivery has an implicit EXECUTE AS context, as well as queue activation that has an explicit one) is usually Service Broker users that discover this problem first.

Comment: Yes, it is the EXECUTE AS context that triggered the problem. You already found the solution.